# Interop workbook not able to access a file while saving

Tags: c#, excel-interop

We are opening an interop workbook to write data and save at a specified location. The excel workbook is declared as

```
   Application excel = new Application();
   protected Workbook workbook;
```

The save function is used

```
   public void SaveFile(string filePath)
   {
       workbook.SaveAs(filePath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
       workbook.Close();
   }
```

The filePath passed is:

```
   C:\Users\newto\Desktop\ExcelDataTLTemplate.xlsx
```

It throws an exception saying

```
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\newto\Desktop\E86DE410'.
```

Comment: It's odd how the exception shows what is seemingly a directory.

Comment: Are you trying to save the file to your own desktop or some other user's? Why `Desktop` instead of the normal location, `My Documents`? Instead of Excel Interop, why not use EPPlus, ClosedXML or NPOI to generate an `xlsx` file without having to install Excel?

Comment: 1. It is done on local machine.

2. Folder location is not a big issue, it can be changed. Plus, this error probably has to do with interop version because it was working fine for many months, recently started using the nuget-installed version of interop.

3. It is possible to change to EPPlus or NPOI but time-consuming. Will keep in mind but at the moment would prefer a fix using interop itself if possible